# Replacing null values in MySQL query in when clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a MySQL Table as One Below

```
CREATE TABLE Test(Name VARCHAR(30));

INSERT INTO Test VALUES ('Name1'), 
                        ('Name2'),
                        (null),
                        ('Name3'),
                        (null),
                        ('Name4');
```

Now when the row is Null I want it to be Displayed as Empty in front end else the value contained in the row

I tried the following query but it ain't worked

```
SELECT CASE Name 
        WHEN NULL 
        THEN '' ELSE Name
       END AS Names
  FROM Test
```

**Output**

```
Name1
Name2

Name3

Name4
```

The link for [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d674b/4)

Thanks for Reply

Comment: You've requested that, in the case the Name is NULL, report an empty string. Change your empty string to "Empty". But you should take a look at the function "COALESCE". It's shorter than a case statement.

Comment: Nps. Wasn't the best reply though! I assumed your "Output" was what you were getting, not what you wanted. Also, assumed you literally wanted "Empty", not an empty string. Even so, coalesce is awesome (even more awesome that IFNULL!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to elaborate on *why* this doesn't work.

A NULL is a value for which comparison yields neither a true nor false result.   That's one of the oddities of the three-tiered logic intrinsic to database programming.

```
NULL = NULL
```

is not true.   It's not false either.   The outcome of any comparison of one value to a NULL value is a NULL result, unless you use the intrinsic SQL "`IS NULL`" operator to test it.

In the form of CASE statement you were using:

```
CASE Value
   WHEN TestValue1 THEN xxx
   WHEN TestValue2 THEN yyy
END
```

a number of equality tests are run against a value.   You *cannot* test for NULL in this form, because you  cannot do equality testing for NULL.   The second form of case:

```
CASE
   WHEN MyValue IS NULL THEN www
   WHEN Condition1 THEN xxx
   WHEN Condition2 THEN yyy
END
```

*does* allow you to use an `IS NULL` expression, which *can* have a TRUE or FALSE value.   Thus, when you want to do NULL testing in a CASE statement, you must *always* use this form.

Also, the NULL test should be the first item in the CASE statement:  because comparing any value against NULL will have an "undetermined" (NULL) boolean value, and the logic of the case will not work properly otherwise.

Answer (score 6):

Null values are special in SQL, you can't treat them as ordinary expressions. Although you can assign `NULL` to a column, you can't compare with it as if it's a normal value; all comparison functions return `NULL` if either of the arguments is `NULL`, and this is treated as false (so `NULL = NULL` and `1 <> NULL` are both false). You're required to use special expressions to compare with `NULL`. The most basic form of this is `<expression> IS NULL` (or `<expression> IS NOT NULL`), but there are also convenience functions `IFNULL()` and `COALESCE()`.

```
SELECT IFNULL(Name, '') AS Names
FROM Test
```

or

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Name IS NULL
            THEN ''
            ELSE Name
       END AS Names
FROM Test
```

For more information, see [3.3.4.6. Working with NULL Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/working-with-null.html) in the MySQL documentation.

Comment: Chuck Norris is the NULL of SQL nothing can be compared to him!